# Can't create Database Master Key with Azure Synapse Analytics (Azure DW) using my admin account created at the birth of the resource

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-synapse

I am opening the query on the master system database.

I've tried:

```
Go
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION by PASSWORD = 'fakepassword';
Go
```

and receive this error message:

```
Msg 15247, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
User does not have permission to perform this action.
```

Answer (score 0):

You should switch from master to your DW and run the following:

`CREATE MASTER KEY;`

See the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/load-data-from-azure-blob-storage-using-polybase?#create-external-tables-for-the-sample-data).